# How to increment or decrement the selected number in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 3 as a text editor. I need a shortcut way to save time by incrementing or decrementing the selected number.

Comment: A Google search for [`sublime text increment number`](https://www.google.com/#q=sublime+text+increment+number) returned the duplicate post as its **first** result. Please do some research before asking next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> next to a number, it gets incremented by 0.1, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> increments it by 10. I'm not sure whether that's default behaviour, I couldn't identify any plugins to be reponsible for this. However, there are [several packages](https://packagecontrol.io/search/increment) available from incrementing numbers.